# XML Parsing works for only subset of larger xml file

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, xpath

```
use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dumper; 

#parsing file
my $dom = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('sample.xml');

#print file to make sure it looks ok
print $dom, "\n";

    #finds shortnames
    my $sn = $dom->findnodes('//shortName');
    print 'ShortName: '.$sn, "\n";

    #finds dbRefernce ids that are of type EC
    my $ids = $dom->findnodes('//dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id');
    my $number =()= $ids =~ /\./gi;
    print 'Result: '.$ids, "\n";

    #finds sequences that have a length
    my $seq = $dom->findnodes('//sequence[@length>1]');
    $seq =~ s/" "/"\n"/;
    print 'Sequence: '.$seq, "\n";
```

I have this code that takes all the shortnames, dbReferences of type EC, and sequences that have length and prints them. I have sample.xml (https://www.dropbox.com/s/dq8ir9f22cnfwrz/Sample.xml)
which is the larger file I need to parse in the end. But I've been using oneentry.xml (https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nxexfig46sw0v6/oneentry.xml), which is just one of the entries from the larger list.

The issue is that the code works for the one entry and prints out:

```
ShortName: 17-beta-HSD 53-alpha-HSD type 2DD-3DD3PGFS
Result: 1.-.-.-1.1.1.3571.1.1.1121.1.1.1881.1.1.2391.1.1.641.3.1.20
Sequence:  MDSKHQCVKLNDGHFMPVLGFGTYAPPEVPRSKALEVTKLAIEAGFRHIDSAHLYNNEEQ VGLAIRSKIADGSVKREDIFYTSKLWSTFHRPELVRPALENSLKKAQLDYVDLYLIHSPM SLKPGEELSPTDENGKVIFDIVDLCTTWEAMEKCKDAGLAKSIGVSNFNRRQLEMILNKP GLKYKPVCNQVECHPYFNRSKLLDFCKSKDIVLVAYSALGSQRDKRWVDPNSPVLLEDPV LCALAKKHKRTPALIALRYQLQRGVVVLAKSYNEQRIRQNVQVFEFQLTAEDMKAIDGLD RNLHYFNSDSFASHPNYPYSDEY
```

But it doesn't output anything for the whole file. What could be different from the two files that makes the script not function the same?

Comment: It seems to me that this data only makes sense in context (in the large document). If that's the case, you will have to consider that when selecting the nodes since `//simpleName` will select *all* simple names in the entire document and place them all together. I think you might wish to group them by `entry`, for example: `entry[name='AK1C3_HUMAN']//shortName` will return all the short names for the `entry` that has that child.

Comment: This kind of selection would be quite simple to do in XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: See it this [fiddle](http://www.xmlplayground.com/WM4jm0) generates the kind of result you are looking for. The HTML in the table on the right is generated when you press `RUN` from your data (upper left box) + a XSLT stylesheet (second box at left). It's an alternative way of extracting the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one important difference in the two files. Your smaller file `oneentry.xml` starts like this:

```
<uniprot> 
    <entry dataset="Swiss-Prot" created="1995-11-01" modified="2014-05-14" version="156"> 
        <accession>P42330</accession> 
        <accession>A8K2V0</accession> 
        ...
```

But your large one `Sample.xml` is slightly different:

```
<uniprot xmlns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://uniprot.org/uniprot 
         http://www.uniprot.org/support/docs/uniprot.xsd">
    <entry dataset="Swiss-Prot" created="1995-11-01" modified="2014-05-14" version="156"> 
        <accession>P42330</accession> 
        <accession>A8K2V0</accession> 
        ...
```

The larger file declares a default namespace: `xmlns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot"` and the smaller one does not. This will affect the selection of the nodes. It doesn't matter if your XML file has a *default* namespace (which requires no prefixing for its tags). The XPath data model ignores that. XPath expressions assume that element selectors belong to *no-namespace* unless they are *explicitly* qualified with a *prefix* that is mapped to the namespace declared in your file for those elements.

There are two ways to fix this:

- Register a namespace/prefix mapping
- Ignore the namespace in your expressions

1. **Register a namespace**

   This is the recommended solution because it will guarantee that you are extracting the correct nodes. You need to choose a prefix. The prefix can be any legal XML identifier `uniprot`, `u`, `up` - you decide. You will need to get the XPath context for your document:

   ```
   my $context = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $dom->documentElement()  );
   $context->registerNs('u', 'http://uniprot.org/uniprot');
   ```

   Now *all* your XPath selectors must be prefixed. Replace

   ```
   //shortName
   //dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id
   //sequence[@length>1]
   ```

   with

   ```
   //u:shortName
   //u:dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id
   //u:sequence[@length>1]
   ```

   (Assuming you chose `u` as the prefix.)

   It's not the case here, but if you had a path with several steps, you would need to qualify the element selectors in each step. For example, if you had to use an absolute expression you would write:

   ```
   /u:uniprot/u:entry/u:reference[16]/u:citation/u:dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id
   ```
2. **Ignore the namespace**

   This is an alternative solution which *can* sometimes be used (usually for small unambiguous selections, which I think is not your case). You select *all* elements (using the *any* element wildcard: `*`) and then filter using the *local* part of the tag name in a predicate (with the `local-name()` function. For this solution you don't have to register any namespaces. You just have to change your expressions.

   ```
   //*[local-name() = 'shortName']
   //*[local-name() = 'dbReference'][@type="EC"]/@id
   //*[local-name() = 'sequence'][@length>1]
   ```

   The problem with this solution is that if you have two elements with the same local name and in different namespaces they will be selected as well. The advantage of this solution, assuming that you don't have any conflicting names, is that you can use it in both your files, the one with namespaces and the one without.

Comment: Nice answer +1. I hope you're happy with my edit. By all means revert it if you prefer your original: I just can't get on with the loud `<h2>` headings

Comment: Does the code you provided in the first box run after $dom is parsed? And then I still use $dom below to find the data I want?

Comment: Yes. You register the namespaces *before* running the XPath expression.

Comment: It should work. You can also try using `$dom->documentElement->findnodes('//u:shortName');` instead of `$dom->findnodes('//u:shortName');`, or add a `.` before the `//`. I believe those are workarounds for bugs in some implementations.